# Django Rest Framework Saying Non-Required Field Is Required

Tags: python, django

**The Backstory**

In Django I have the models

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=False,unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.TextField()

class Person(models.Model ): 
    firstname = models.TextField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,null= True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Where each person has an address and a company.(both non required fields)

In DRF I have the serializers.

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'firstname',  'address','company')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response['address'] = AddressSerializer(instance.address).data
        response['company'] = CompanySerializer(instance.company).data
        return response
```

and the ViewSets

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter,DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id','company','firstname','middlename','lastname',)
    search_fields = ('firstname','middlename','lastname',)

class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter,DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id','name',)
    search_fields = ('name',)

class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Address.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['id','street']
```

**The Issue**

When posting the data `{"firstname":"foo"}` to this serializer, it returns a 400 error code saying. `{"company": ["This field is required."]}`.

The odd thing is, the address field is set up the *seemingly* exact same way as the company field but does not throw this error.

In order to make this work, you must post `{"firstname":"foo","company":null}` to the serializer, which seems a little silly considering that the address field works just fine.

Does anybody have any idea what would be causing this issue and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What happens if you also set `blank=True` for those fields (in the model, just like `null=True`)?

Comment: @slider same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `blank=True` in addition to `null=True` in your ForeignKey constructor, like this:

```
address = models.ForeignKey(Address,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: This throws the same error as described above. What's odd is that "blank=True" isn't needed on the address field.

Comment: I think that's because you have a required field in your Company constructor, but not in the Address constructor.

Comment: I just set a default value for the name field in the company model and it sill throws the error.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 Did you run and apply the migrations?

Comment: Could this perhaps be something in the ViewSet? I can provide that code if needed.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 yeah if you could update your question with the ViewSet that might help

Comment: it seemed that having to add blank and null to BOTH model fields did the trick. I am not sure why it'd be different for one field vs the other but oh well. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try changing it to this

```
fields = ('id', 'firstname',  'address','company',)
```

Comment: I believe that is what it is currently. You mean in the person serializer?

Comment: @Bigbob556677 notice the comma at the end

Comment: Gotcha. My bad. But it throws the same error nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated exactly what you have wrote but found no such problem as posted in the question. No error was thrown.

```html
#My Models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=False,unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.TextField()

class Person(models.Model ):
    firstname = models.TextField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,null= True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

```html
#My Viewset

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'company', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname',)
    search_fields = ('firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname',)


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'name',)
    search_fields = ('name',)


class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Address.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['id', 'street']
```

```html
#My Serializer

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'firstname',  'address','company')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response['address'] = AddressSerializer(instance.address).data
        response['company'] = CompanySerializer(instance.company).data
        return response
```

```html
#My tests
class PersonTests(APITestCase):

    def test_create_person(self):
        url = reverse('person-list')
        data = {"firstname": "foo"}
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        print(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

[image: Test Results:]